# Why do I get "is not a constant expression" error in this case ? (templates)

Tags: c++, templates, itk

I am trying to implement some kind of [numpy.where()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for my ITK images in C++. ITK's way seems to be with Functors. I am not very experienced with templates, so my whole approach might be flawed, but here is my go:

```
using MASK_IMAGE_TYPE = itk::Image<unsigned short, 3>;

template<class T, T value, T if_equal, T if_n_equal> class WhereFunctor
{
private:
    T v = value;
    T e = if_equal;
    T n = if_n_equal;
public:
    WhereFunctor() = default;
    ~WhereFunctor() = default;
    inline T operator()(const T& in_value)
    {
        return in_value == value ? if_equal : if_n_equal;
    }
};

template<typename T> typename T::Pointer where(
        typename T::Pointer& img,
        typename T::PixelType value,
        typename T::PixelType if_equal,
        typename T::PixelType if_n_equal)
{
    auto filter = itk::UnaryFunctorImageFilter<T, T, WhereFunctor<typename T::PixelType, value, if_equal, if_n_equal>>::New();
    filter->SetInPlace(false);
    filter->SetInput(img);
    filter->Update();
    typename T::Pointer ret_img = filter->GetOutput();
    return ret_img;
}
```

When I try to call this where function with:
`auto img = where<MASK_IMAGE_TYPE>(my_image, 0, 1, 0);`, I get the following error:

```
: In instantiation of ‘typename T::Pointer where(typename T::Pointer&, typename T::PixelType, typename T::PixelType, typename T::PixelType) [with T = itk::Image<short unsigned int, 3>; typename T::Pointer = itk::SmartPointer<itk::Image<short unsigned int, 3> >; typename T::PixelType = short unsigned int]’:
:23:55:   required from here
:58:124: error: ‘value’ is not a constant expression
   58 |     auto filter = itk::UnaryFunctorImageFilter<T, T, WhereFunctor<typename T::PixelType, value, if_equal, if_n_equal>>::New();
      |                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
:58:124: note: in template argument for type ‘short unsigned int’
:58:124: error: ‘if_equal’ is not a constant expression
:58:124: note: in template argument for type ‘short unsigned int’
:58:124: error: ‘if_n_equal’ is not a constant expression
:58:124: note: in template argument for type ‘short unsigned int’
```

I think I understand that such an error can be due to type indeterminacy at compile type, but in this case I do not understand where it comes from.

Comment: You are using a runtime value (for example the 'value' argument of 'where') as a template parameter, which is a compile time entity.

Comment: @BasGroothedde Thank you for your comment. Aren't my where arguments (0, 1, 0) known at compile time because hard coded ?

Comment: Also in `WhereFunctor` you don't need any template paramenter beyond `T`.

Comment: @Louis when the compiler compiles `where` it has to produce code which works for every value of the parameters it might take.

Comment: @Louis The fact that the constants used as parameters to the `where` function `(0, 1, 0)` does not imply that the receiving end is also a constant expression. If you want to provide these values compile-time, add the `value`, `if_equal` and `if_n_equal` template parameters to the `where` function too and just forward them.

Comment: @al3c Thank you for your time ! I added these template params to the functor because I do not know another way for the functor to get them, as it is instantiated internally by the itk::UnaryFunctorImageFilter. It seems that if I want to stick to this filter for my handcrafted numpy.where, I will have to follow Bas' recommendation and add the template parmas to the where function too. (Big) Downside is that this where function will only take compile-time parameters :/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have needlessly many template parameters. You could follow the way it is done in a corresponding test. Define your [function](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/047fa6934ac32711d1d7b84fa6eb81c72db01960/Modules/Filtering/ImageFilterBase/test/itkGeneratorImageFilterGTest.cxx#L63-L67), set it via [filter->SetFunctor()](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/047fa6934ac32711d1d7b84fa6eb81c72db01960/Modules/Filtering/ImageFilterBase/test/itkGeneratorImageFilterGTest.cxx#L185-L209) and call `Update()`.

Comment: Thank you for this ! I did not know the filter->SetFunctor() method existed. I still find it strange that the filter instantiates a default functor before letting you set a custom one. Anyway thanks I posted an answer with a working example.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, a corrected version of the code would be:

```
template<class T> class WhereFunctor
{
private:
    T v = 0;
    T e = 0;
    T n = 1;
public:
    WhereFunctor() = default;
    WhereFunctor(T value, T if_equal, T if_n_equal)
        : v(value), e(if_equal), n(if_n_equal)
    {}
    ~WhereFunctor() = default;
    inline T operator()(const T& in_value)
    {
        return in_value == v ? e : n;
    }
    inline bool operator!=(const WhereFunctor<T>& other) { return v!=other.v || e!=other.e || n!=other.n; }
};

template<typename T>
typename T::Pointer where(typename T::Pointer& img, typename T::PixelType value, typename T::PixelType if_equal, typename T::PixelType if_n_equal)
{
    auto filter = itk::UnaryFunctorImageFilter<T, T, WhereFunctor<typename T::PixelType>>::New();
    filter->SetFunctor(WhereFunctor<typename T::PixelType>(value, if_equal, if_n_equal));
    filter->SetInPlace(false);
    filter->SetInput(img);
    filter->Update();
    typename T::Pointer ret_img = filter->GetOutput();
    return ret_img;
}
```